# How to hide and show the same element in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've just started using Angular.js for a side project of mine, but I've come to a point where I'm really, really stuck. I want a html element to be clicked on, replaced by a loading bar and come back after the loading's finished.

I've tried using `ng-hide` and `ng-show`, but it only works if I have something like this:

```
<a href="" ng-click="click = !click" ng-hide="click">{{action}}</a> <a href="#" ng-click="click = !click" ng-show="click">Undo</a>
```

Is this a way to accomplish dynamic showing/hiding through pure Angular? I'm trying to find solutions before I have to resort to Jquery.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this loading of asynchronous data using $http?

Comment: question is how you will identify loading is finished? not `ng-hide` and `ng-show`

Answer (score 0):

`ng-hide` and `ng-show` are the right way to do that.

Take a look on [angular-spinner](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner) too. It coulds help you.